# CakePHP Not Loading New Schema/Fields

Tags: cakephp, caching, schema

I'm sure the cause of this is something obvious which I'll be facepalming about later, but I'm completely stuck.

I've added a new column to my `Users` tabled, called `developer`.  It's a `tinyint(1)` treated as boolean by CakePHP.  I've added other fields like it (e.g. other bools) without incident.

For some strange reason though, CakePHP is not picking up on this change.  After reading several other questions about similar topics I've ensured that my debug level in `app/Config/core.php` is set to `2`, I've deleted all of the files in the various `app/tmp/cache/*` sub-directories.  However, nothing seems to be doing the trick.

**What could I be missing that's causing CakePHP to not detect the schema changes?**

---

**EDIT**

I just tested the change in our staging environment which, apart from being Linux and not OS X, is the same as my local (OS X) development environment and I **am** seeing the new field there.  I'm guessing it's *not* an OS issue, but I suppose it is worth noting.

Comment: Can you see CakePHP executing `describe` SQL queries? Also, are you sure your application is using file-based caching? If APC is installed, CakePHP may be using memory for caching model/schema information

Comment: I cleared the cache files again and turned on the sql_dump element in my default.ctp.  No describe calls showing up there.  app/Config/core.php has $engine = "file".

Comment: The cache files did regenerate when I reloaded the page and while I'm still not seeing the new column when I pr(...) a user record, I opened the file tmp/cache/models/row_cake_model_default_xxxxxxx__users and see the following at the end: s:9:"developer";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:7:"boolean";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";s:1:"0";s:6:"length";i:1;}  So, it at least appears to be picking up the change.  Why would it not load with the user record?

Comment: Ok, so the cache should not be the problem. What *exactly* isn't working when you say it 'doesn't see the schema change'?

Comment: If I try to access $user['User']['developer'] I get an "Undefined index: developer" error.  Likewise, doing a pr($user) is dumping the user record but no developer field is listed.

Comment: Is it possible you explicitly defined the `fields` to retrieve with the query? Also, since you're talking about a user (just thinking out loud here); is this the information of the *current* user? May this be the information stored inside the `$_SESSION`? Otherwise, it may be worth checking the SQL performed to see if the queries also are missing the `developer` column?

Comment: How are you testing whether or not Cake is "picking up the changes"?  (If it's a form, please post form code.)

Comment: Aha!  We're getting somewhere.  The $user object I'm working with is the one returned by $this->Auth->user().  I checked those returned by the query in /users/index and the developer field was there.  I logged out and back in and now it's working.  I guess I didn't realize that the Auth component was caching the logged in user.  If you add a "proper" answer referring to this conversation above I will happily accept it.  Thanks so much for assisting with this!

Comment: @theraccoonbear just did, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be checking the information of the *currently logged-in user*, which is stored inside the session after a successful log-in (see [**Accessing the logged in Used**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user))

To update this information, log out and log in again to have the session-data updated.

Comment: Thanks again for your speedy assistance.